# How to activate Virtualenv when a Python script starts?

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron, python

I want to schedule a python script to run using cron on certain dates, the problem is that in order for `example.py` to work, `example-env` has to be activated, is there a way to make `example.py` activate its own virtualenv whenever cron execute it?

if not, then do I have to create a bash script `bash.sh` that contains

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
workon example-env
python2 example.py
```

and then schedule that to be executed by cron on certain dates? Or do I have to do something else?

Both ways are fine with me, I just want to know the correct way to do it. Perhaps I prefer the bash script method, since I have many Python files to run, so if I put them all inside a bash script and schedule that, it seems easier for me, but again I don't know the correct way to do it, therefore I'm asking for advice.

Comment: It there a “Correct” way? Maybe there is another way.

Comment: @richard i'll be happy to know about it. I just formulated my question that way coz it never occurred to me that there might be a better way but I love learning

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can just start the `example.py` with the full path to `example-env/bin/python2`.

Alternatively change the shebang line of the `example.py` to use that executable, make that file executable (`chmod +x example.py`) and leave out python and use the full path to `example.py` to start it:

```
#!/full/path/to/example-env/bin/python2
```